# Show that the graph $G^M$ is connected if and only if $M$ is irreducible

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, connectedness

> A symmetric matrix $M$ is said to be reducible if $\exists$ some permutation matrix $P$ such that $$P^{-1}MP=\begin{bmatrix} X&0\\0&Y\end{bmatrix}$$

Consider a graph $G^M=(V,E)$ associated with a symmetric matrix $M=[a_{ij}]_{n\times n}$ as follows:

$V(G)=\{1,2\ldots ,n\}$ and vertex $i$ is adjacent to $j$ if $a_{ij}\neq 0$.

> Show that $G^M$ is connected if and only if $M$ is irreducible.

**Attempt**:

Let $G^M$ is disconnected  ,so the adjacency matrix of $G^M$ has the form \begin{bmatrix} B&0\\0&C\end{bmatrix}

But how to link the adjacency matrix of a graph to the matrix $M$ from which the graph $G^M$ is constructed?

Comment: Hint: The adjacency matrix of $G^M$ doesn't necessarily have that form, but there is some renaming of the vertices (i.e. some _permutation_ of the vertex labels) that makes it have that form.